# Why does my form display a generic name in the VS IDE?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I changed the name of my main form to "FormMain", yet in the IDE it still says, "Form1.cs[Design]" and "Form1.cs"

Although not a showstopper, I find this both irritating and distracting.

How can I rectify this revolting development?

Comment: Did you change the file name or the name of the Form in properties??

Comment: Where did you rename it?  And where is it still showing the name you don't want?

Comment: In the VS IDE Properties pane I changed the form's Name property. I didn't change the name of the file itself (in Windows Explorer or so). So am I to assume that what it's showing me is it's "Windows Explorer" name? The VS IDE is where the name is showing ("Form1.cs" and "Form1.cs[Design]").

Answer (score 1):

If you changed the filename of `Form1.cs` to `FormMain.cs` in solution explorer then it should be ok. I think you may have clicked on the form and changed the `name` property in the properties view to `FormMain.cs`, this will only change the name that is displayed in the form's title bar. Change the filename too.

Comment: the Properties pane in VS shows "FormWorkerMain System.Windows.Forms.Form" but the tab above the form itself displays "Form1.cs[Design]" and "Form1.cs"

That seems confusing to me.

Comment: I changed the name in VS via right-click "Rename" to something more specific than "Form1" but I would think it would automatically do that for you. But then again, Windows does/does not do a lot of things that are very irritating to me.